# Is there a way to show axis labels of full dataset while filtering a chart?

Tags: reporting-services, bar-chart, ssrs-2012

For example, if the dataset is grabbing all sales data for a region but a single bar chart is for a single store. The bar chart is looking at sales for products, say fruits. Now region wide there are apples, oranges, pears, bananas being sold. But this store only sold a few apples and bananas. The bar chart axis will only show apples and bananas when you add a filter to only show the stores data. Is there a way to show all fruits region wide but with zero values?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the chart to have all the axis values, they must be present in the dataset. So in the SQL you would need to start with all the categories and then `LEFT JOIN` the filtered data to this.